# How to disabled shadow copy in nunit from console exe

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit

I am trouble with loading `Nunit` test dll. The test dll is using some other exe which copied few directory and files when they builds.

I have recevied that error when call `test.dll` from nunitconsole.exe

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
```

The console parameters are as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit-console.exe" /xml:"C:\abc.xml" "D:\Project\UnitTestProjct\RGTestingToolTestProject\NUnitTestProject\bin\Debug\NUnitTestProject.dll"
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `/noshadow:false` in your console parameters.

the detailed information about the `Nunit` parameters are given that [Link](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2.5)