# C# NUnit Test Behaves Differently than when Run Directly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

So I have some code (I did not write) that works when run or debugged as a unit test, but when the *exact same* code is run normally with the program, it behaves differently. I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with NUnit installed running on Windows 7 64-bit. To run as a unit test, I use the Visual Studio test explorer. I'm not that familiar with unit testing, so I'm really hoping that I just overlooked something simple.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
//The code in question
public static void TryThis()
{
    USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface usbIa = new USBInterface("0");
    String[] list = usbIa.getDeviceList(); //empty when calling from Main()
    Assert.IsNotEmpty(list);
}

//A unit test that calls this code
[Test]
public static void CallingFunction()
{
    TryThis(); //list gets populated and assert passes
}

//Main function that calls this code when program running - doesn't 
public static void Main()
{
    TryThis(); //list remains empty and assert fails
}
```

The code calls a DLL from System32 (setupapi.dll to be specific), and this function call is where the difference in behavior occurs, so I cannot step through to see exactly what causes the different behavior. There are no [SetUp] or [TearDown] attributes or anything like that in the entire solution. Only [TestFixture] and [Test].

My question is: **What could possibly be different when calling TryThis() from a unit test as opposed to Main()?**

What I've tried:

- Running the test, as well as Main(), in both debug and release mode.
- Running the test, as well as Main(), in both x86 and x64 architecture.
- Specifying the full absolute path of the DLL to ensure that the same DLL is being loaded in both cases.
- Copying the code directly into Main() and CallingFunction() to avoid any function calls.
- Putting the [Test] attribute above Main() itself and running as a test (this works when run as a test, not when run normally).
- Debugging and stepping through the code one instruction at a time: between both cases (debugged as test and debugged normally), all variables (autos and locals) are identical right up to the point of the DLL function call.
- Compiling my code as its own DLL library and calling it from another application (list is still empty) to rule out issues with Visual Studio.
- Running Visual Studio as an administrator to rule out permissions issues.
- A bunch of other combinations of functions calling functions, defining functions as tests, etc. In all cases, the code only works when run as a test.
- Trying it on a different computer (same OS).

I would greatly appreciate any feedback or ideas, no matter how crazy they are. Ultimately I just need to be be able to use this code in an application. Thanks!

Comment: did you check the config file differences between testproject and your application?

Comment: No. I'll lookup how to do that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's all the same project. My setup is really very simple. The 3 functions I listed are all in the same file as well, just like I show them.

Comment: Have you checked the event log for any errors logged by the dll? It could be some sort of security issue, where the unit tests are run with different permissions than when running the app directly or through VS

Comment: When running tests with NUnit (console or GUI), it uses Shadow Copy Cache, which may cause some unexpected behavior - you may try disabling it (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337677/how-to-disabled-shadow-copy-in-nunit-from-console-exe)

Comment: PSA - I still haven't figured it out, but my team has managed to work around this issue (we found another library that does what we want). I'll leave the question open in case somebody else is suffering a similar issue.